# How do a single layer perceptron separate the feature space

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

I'm trying to understand how a single layer perceptron would separate the feature space into classes. Let's assume the single layer perceptron consists of 3 neurons which take a two dimensional feature vector, computes the activation state, applies the activation function on it and returns a class label. The question is, whether I can predict HOW the feature space will be separated into classes.

Comment: Do you want to distinguish three different classes?

Comment: If there are three neurons in the ouptut layer, the feature space will be separated into three classes. What i want to know is, how the classes would look like if i use the step function or a sigmoid function as activation function in each neuron.